# How to ensure Spark send at least one partition per worker

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following simplified code:

```py
import socket
from pyspark import TaskContext

def f(_):
    partition_id = TaskContext().partitionId()
    return partition_id, socket.gethostname()


rdd.partitionBy(...).mapPartition(f).collect()
```

The problem is that sometimes **the same worker gets two partitions and one worker is idle** (I'm working with three Worker nodes). For example, the above example prints:

```
1, "Computer 1"

2, "Computer 1"
```

Is there a way to ensure that any worker processes at least one partition (if there are enough partitions)? I don't care which node processes which partition, I just want to ensure that parallelism is optimized.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected. Spark will do "its best" to distribute the data equally among the workers, but it doesn't always do as we expected. Try this example:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ('a', 1),
    ('a', 2),
    ('b', 3),
    ('b', 4),
    ('c', 5),
])

def print_partitions(lst):
    for i, a in enumerate(lst):
        print(i, a)

for i in range(1, 20):
    print(f'test {i} partitions:')
    print_partitions(rdd.partitionBy(i).glom().collect())
    print('---\n')
```

The **more partitions** you make, the **higher chance** you'll have your data distributed equally (i.e. all `a` in one partition etc)

Comment: The problem is that my `mapPartition` function performance is being degraded. I expected to have some parameter like `num-executors` or `spark.executor.instances` but for partitions

Answer (score 0):

**In general, No you can't *guarantee* this.**

You can encourage it, by waiting for [data locality](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-locality), increasing [data replication](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#:%7E:text=by%20the%20NameNode.-,Data%20Replication,are%20replicated%20for%20fault%20tolerance.), or increasing the number of [partitions](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-partitioning-understanding/).

Technically if you replicated your data to every node, you should always have a node with your data, but that's expensive space wise and would not be a good practice unless you really required it.